# RHive Wrong FS Failure

Tags: r, hadoop, hive

when I am trying to connect to the Hiveserver via rhive.connect() I get the following error:

```
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: hdfs:/rhive/lib/rhive_udf.jar,
```

The hiveserver output is the following:

```
converting to local hdfs:///rhive/lib/rhive_udf.jar
Failed to read external resource hdfs:///rhive/lib/rhive_udf.jar
```

I am using the latest CDH4 Version.
Thanks